# How to bind variables to conditional statement when using jOOQ to build SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I'm using jOOQ-3.11.9 to build SQL. The following is my code:

```
String sql = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL)
        .select(DSL.asterisk())
        .from(table("service"))
        .where("name = ?", "service1")
        .getSQL();
```

What I expect is

```
select * from service where (name = "service1")
```

But the result is

```
select * from service where (name = ?)
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: This question was also asked on github, here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8242

Comment: there should be a bind variable with a value based on '?' character unless we use getSQL with ParameterType.INLINED. like DSL.select().from(table("table")).where(field("field1").in(mnoIdValues).and(field("field2").eq(<dynamic-value>))).getQuery().getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected. The default [`Settings.statementType`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#statementType) value is [`StatementType.PREPARED_STATEMENT`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/StatementType.html#PREPARED_STATEMENT), so jOOQ by default generates bind value placeholders in your SQL string, which can be used for execution in other tools, such as JDBC, Spring, etc.

You can pass the [`ParamType.INLINE`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/ParamType.html#INLINED) value to the [`getSQL()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL-org.jooq.conf.ParamType-) method, or specify [`Settings.withStatementType(StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#withStatementType-org.jooq.conf.StatementType-)

Please consider the explanation in the Javadoc for more details:
https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL--

Answer (score 0):

You should use the field name from jOOQ-generated classes:

```
String sql = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL)
    .select(DSL.asterisk())
    .from(YOURENTITY)
    .where(YOURENTITY.NAME.eq(nameParam))
    .getSQL();
```

`YOURENTITY` should be the jOOQ-generated class in your project. `nameParam` would then be an argument passed to the method wrapping the above query.

jOOQ has pretty good docs with lots of examples:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/where-clause/

Comment: While the manual(http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual-single-page/#jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder) imply I can use jooq-sql-builder without code-gen. Is it a bug?